# request.GetResponse(); returns 407 (Proxy Authentication Required) even though correct credentials are supplied

Tags: c#, .net, proxy

I'm developing an application (in C#) which sends http requests.
Everything works fine as long as there's no Proxy with authentication involved.

Here's my code:

```
request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = length;
request.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("hans", "maulwurf"); 
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("hans", "maulwurf");

using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            // now send it
            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Flush();
            requestStream.Close();
        }
WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
```

On the last line i always get 407. The credentials work in ie/ff.

Does anyone have suggestions what the problem might be?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a proxy set? Have you tried passing the `domain` along with your credentials?

Comment: Compare the headers sent from the browser with the headers sent from your webrequest, for example using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). Perhaps the domain is missing.

Comment: I haven't explicitly set one, but stepping through the code, I can see that the correct proxy (from IE settings) is used.

Comment: thanks for your replies. I'll give fiddler a try. But i don't think passing the domain is neccecary, as the proxy I'm currently using is running locally on my computer with its own user database.

Comment: @user1774510 try setting `request.Proxy = request.DefaultWebProxy;`. Also, just an FYI you don't need to call `Flush`/`Close` on the stream when you wrap it with a `using` statement.

Comment: thanks james, neither flushing, nor closing anymore :)
unfortunetly explicitly setting the proxy doesn't solve my problem, because the same proxy is being used either way

Comment: This is what I found out using fiddler:
The first request from IE contains this field: 
Proxy-Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB7IIogMAAwAuAAAABgAGACgAAAAGAbEdAAAAD05QVEVHMUhWUw==
and the first request from my application contains same with one small difference: 
Proxy-Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAt7II4gMAAwAuAAAABgAGACgAAAAGAbEdAAAAD05QVEVHMUhWUw== 
The only difference is ...B7IIo... in IE and ...t7II4... in my app. 
Is there any way to figure out what this means?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to also specify the proxy server. like this, for example,

```
IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("<Server IP>", <Server Port>);
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("hans", "maulwurf"); 
request.Proxy = proxy;
```

Comment: setting a breakpoint at request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri); shows me that the correct proxy is being used. And I set the credentials on that object, so it should do the same thing your code does. I think the problem is somewhere else. thanks anyway